# What does "Pixels per foot" mean in digital images?

Tags: image, resolution

When I am reading about the resolution of a digital image from the following link http://www.rideau-info.com/photos/whatis.html, I confused at the following Paragraph:

> If the field of view is 20 feet across, a 3 megapixel camera will be resolving that view at 102 pixels per foot. If that same shot was taken with an 18 Mp camera it would be resolving that view at 259 pixels per foot, 2.5 times more resolution than a 3 Mp camera.

Here, how come the author is arriving at the conclusion: "102 pixels per foot and 259 pixels"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 3MP camera, in that article, is 2048 wide x 1536 high. Think of 2048 pixels across as 2048 boxes laid in a straight line. Now, if you were to divide these equally amongst 20 sections (20 feet of field of view), you would get ~120 boxes per section. Hence, the logic behind 102 pixels per foot. Similar reasoning is used for the 18MP camera which is 5184 W x 3546 H. 5184 divided into 20 is ~259.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have one more doubt. I am assuming the image is gray scale. So it's true that 2048*1536 divided by 1024^2 is 3 MB. What will be the size, if the image is colored one/RGB (Assuming it's not compressed).

Comment: That is not as straight forward. Size of the resulting image will depend on several factors such as format (e.g. JPG, TIFF, RAW, GIF, PNG, etc), compression ratio (e.g. no compression, fine, medium, etc). etc etc. You can, however calculate theoretical maximum size for an image by taking the total count of pixels and then bits for color per pixel (e.g. 16-bit, 24-bit, 32-bit, etc) etc etc.